# How to bake multiple objects into one texture file

Tags: uv, baking

### Background

I have a scene:

[image: scene]

with multiple meshes and am trying to bake the textures. Ideally, I would want to fit all of the textures into one HDR file and export the baked texture in a JPG format. I would like to use this for my exported glb scene. Also, I'm pretty new to Blender.

### Goal

Unwrap all meshes and bake the textures into one JPG file.

### Problem

Too many objects; quite difficult to fit everything in one texture file.

### Current Approach

- Divide the scene into "segments" and bake these segments into separate texture files.

  - For example: bake environment meshes (grass, rocks, trees, etc) into one texture file, and bake meshes of animals (dogs, cats, etc) into another. Below is just an example of what I baked so far:
    [image: baked texture 1]

[image: baked texture 2]

Think it's not a good approach since in the end, there will be multiple texture files and it will take time for my scene to load.

### Goals (Please advise on this)

- I would like to be advised on a way to pack all of the textures into one file without separating them (if possible).

### Note

- This is what it looks like when I try to cram everything inside 1 texture file.
  [image]

Comment: hello, why do you say that it is "quite difficult to fit everything in one texture file"?

Comment: Hi @moonboots, well there is just too many meshes. It's too hard to adjust texel density so that every mesh is roughly the same.

Comment: Question edited.